# PHP/SQL mapping prices from one table to another

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have a page that displays info inside of multiple html tables but the info is all supplied via SQL database table. The only issue I'm having now is for pricing. In this case, price is based off of Type and Size of meter and service preformed. For this example, there is a 4" compound meter and it is an onsite survey and test, as shown here:

[image]

Here is the code for those three fields in that table:

```
<tr style="border: none;">
<td style="border: none; text-align: left;">Service Preformed:</td>
<td style="border: none; text-align: right;"><? echo $row['workOrderType2'];?>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr style="border: none;">
<td style="border: none; text-align: left;">Meter Type:</td>
<td style="border: none; text-align: right;"><? echo $row['meterType'];?>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr style="border: none;">
<td style="border: none; text-align: left;">Meter Size:</td>
<td style="border: none; text-align: right;"><? echo $row['meterSize'];?>&nbsp;</td>
```

This is all correct, but I need to fill a pricing table with the price based on these 3 attriutes. I have a pricing DB table that looks like this:

[image]

And here is the html table for pricing:

[image]

Basically, for this particular example, the html table should say $520 next to the Onsite Survey and Test row in the html pricing table which would correspond to priceID '2' in the db table.

I'm very unsure on how to create this so that it can take the values from the first html table (workOrderType2, meterType and meterSize) and match them to the pricing table to fill only the necessary row with the right price.

UPDATE:

If it's easier, I have a staging table with everything that makes up these html tables. Is there a way to make a trigger or something that could use the three conditions in the DB table to populate the empty price field in the staging table with the price from the pricing table?

Comment: Tip: don't store '$'

Comment: Oh Didn't know that. I may be able to fix that up later and just put the dollar sign in the html table